# Acquire Marker's location on Android using Google maps api

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I'm having trouble getting the location of a marker which i have placed on the map. After placing the marker on the map I press a button to show a Toast displaying the latitude and longitude of the marker but the app is force closing.

this is my method

```
 public void markerLoc(View view)
    {
        LatLng lat = marker.getPosition();
        double lat1 = lat.latitude;
        double lng1 = lat.longitude;
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"lat: "+lat1+" & long: "+lng1,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

Basically i want to add a marker to the map and on pressing the button the marker's location is to be shown. If the marker is moved the new location is to be shown on pressing the button.

Thanks in advance :)

my activity

public class Locate extends FragmentActivity implements LocationListener {

    GoogleMap googleMap;
    double latitude,longitude;
    static int i=1;
    GPSTracker gps;
    Marker marker;
    LatLng lat;
    //Location location;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.locate);
        int status = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(getBaseContext());


        if(status!= ConnectionResult.SUCCESS){

            int requestCode = 10;
            Dialog dialog = GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(status, this, requestCode);
            dialog.show();

        }else {


            SupportMapFragment fm = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);


            googleMap = fm.getMap();


            googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);


            LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);


            Criteria criteria = new Criteria();


            String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);


            Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

            if(location!=null){
                onLocationChanged(location);
            }
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 20000, 0, this);
        }


    }



    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

        TextView tvLocation = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_location);
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"lat: "+location.getLatitude()+"long: "+location.getLatitude(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

       latitude = location.getLatitude();

        longitude = location.getLongitude();


        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);


        googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));


        googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(15));


        tvLocation.setText("Latitude:" +  latitude  + ", Longitude:"+ longitude );



    }


    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
    public void Dest(View view){
        if(i==1) {
            i=0;
            gps = new GPSTracker(Locate.this);


            if(gps.canGetLocation()){

                double latitude = gps.getLatitude();
                double longitude = gps.getLongitude();


                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your Location is - \nLat: " + latitude + "\nLong: " + longitude, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
               marker = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                        .position(new LatLng(latitude+0.0005, longitude+0.0005))
                        .title("Your destination")
                        .draggable(true));
            }else{

                gps.showSettingsAlert();
            }

        }
        else
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"You can add only one destination spot",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    public void Clear(View view)
    {
        i=1;
        googleMap.clear();
    }

    public void markerLoc(View view) {

        if (marker != null) {
            lat = marker.getPosition();
            double lat1 = lat.latitude;
            double lng1 = lat.longitude;
            if(getBaseContext() != null) {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "lat: " + lat1 + " & long: " + lng1, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }
```

}
my xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Location activity"
        android:id="@+id/tv_location"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />
    <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="500dp"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">


        <Button
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Add destination"
            android:onClick="Dest"
            android:id="@+id/dest" />

        <Button
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Clear"
            android:id="@+id/clear"
            android:onClick="Clear"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="MarkerLoc"
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:onClick="markerLoc"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    </RelativeLayout>



</LinearLayout>
```

The Dest button adds a new marker which is just a little away from the current location. If i move the marker to a new location and then press markerLoc button the location does not seem to change , it always shows the first location.

Comment: check whether getBaseContext() is null using if(getBaseContext()!=null){}, same thing check for marker also if(marker != null ){}

Answer (score 0):

```
public void markerLoc(View view)
{
    if(marker != null)
    {
        LatLng lat = marker.getPosition();
        double lat1 = lat.latitude;
        double lng1 = lat.longitude;
        if(getBaseContext() != null)
        {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"lat: "+lat1+" & long:     "+lng1,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This seems to work but how do i update the marker's position ? whenever i press the button it shows me the same longitude and latitude no matter where i move it .

Comment: could't understand can you please elaborate your question ?. As am understand you need to use maker listener.

Comment: I would like to add a maker on to the map. If i press the show_location button, it should show me the latitude and longitude of the marker which i have just added. When i try moving the marker and then press the show_location button, the values of the new latitude and longitude is not shown, instead the toast is showing the previous location. How do i update my marker's location ?

Comment: can you please show your whole activity, as am not getting exact problem.